# How to render same react component for different routes with different value props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to ask whether it is possible to render same react component for different routes but with different value props:

I have something like this:

```
   <Switch>
      <Route
         exact
         path="/something1"
         render={props => (
            <SomeComponent
             {...props}
             buttonStyle="#65BDE0"
          />
       )}
    />
    <Route
       exact
       path="/something2"
       render={props => (
          <SomeComponent
           {...props}
           buttonStyle="#FFFFFF"
          />
       )}
    />
     <Route
       exact
       path="/something3"
       render={props => (
          <SomeComponent
           {...props}
           buttonStyle="#000000"
          />
       )}
    />
    </Switch>
```

As you can see I have three different routes with the same component but the buttonStyle is different for each route. Is there a way how to simplify this or some better apporach how to handle this ? For example with one Route component ? Thank you.

Comment: You could access this.props.location in `ComponentDidMount` of `SomeComponent` and set `buttonStyle` accordingly. Also, make sure `SomeComponent` is wrapped with `withRouter`.

Comment: Do I need to use withRouter if SomeComponent is render by Route ?... that's why I have {...props}.

Comment: Correct, you probably don't need to wrap it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that you can do this with one `<Route />` component since a Route can have only one path.

However, you could make it a bit cleaner by creating an array of routes.

It could look something like this:

```
const routesWithProps = [
  {
    path: '/something1',
    props: {
      buttonStyle: '#65BDE0'
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/something2',
    props: {
      buttonStyle: '#FFFFFF'
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/something3',
    props: {
      buttonStyle: '#000000'
    }
  },
];

<Switch>
  {
    routesWithProps.map(route => (
      <Route
         exact
         path={route.path}
         key={route.path}
         render={props => <SomeComponent {...props} {...route.props} />} 
      />
    ))
  }
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on where you want to keep the logic. If you want to make the route simple you could have a single route component with `something/:btn`, and then in the `<SomeComponent />` have the button rendering logic. You could have the `/:btn` be the colored hash you want the button to be in, or some arbitary id number only your app could decipher.

An example would be

```js
export const SomeComponent = ({history}) => {
  const param = history.params.btn;
  if(param === 1) {
    return <div>Here i can add specific things </div>
  }
  // and so on

}
```

This is not because it is the best solution, but maybe this idea will kickstart how to want to do it. Good luck